# Possible to pass in an array to match by?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have the below query that works for a single match but I'm trying to filter with this query by multiple user ids that I have in an array. Instead of looping over the same query string to update the `user_id` every time to execute a new query is it possible to use an array? Thinking of something like `IN` for SQL

```
 db.tests.aggregate([{
   "$match": {
      "user_id": "aassaas"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$user_id",
      "count": {
        "$sum": {
          "$size": {
            "$objectToArray": "$days"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: $in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/ ?

Comment: use [**`$in`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator `[
 {"$match": { "user_id": { "$in": arrayOfIds }}},
  {"$group": {
    "_id": "$user_id",
    "count": {
     "$sum": { "$size":{"$objectToArray": "$days"} }
   }
 }}
]`